# Intuition behind equation for finding arc length in polar coordinate

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, arc-length

I know how to derive the equation for finding arc length in polar coordinates but I don't understand this:

Given a parametric equation let L be the length of the arc from point t = a to to t = b we have:

$L = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}\frac{dt}{dt} = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt$.

To turn this equation into the polar coordinate version we can assume the parametric equation is $x = rcos\theta$ and $y = rsin\theta$ (so t = $\theta$) and after substitution we should get the equation $L = \int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}\sqrt{r^2 +r'^2} d\theta$.

So what I don't' understand is the "intuition" behind why $dx^2 + dy^2 \neq dr^2$. Clearly, if  $dx^2 + dy^2 = dr^2$ L would equal $\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}|r'| d\theta$ which "intuitively" can't be correct (length cannot be just a function of slope).

I'm not entirely sure how to explain what I mean by "intuition" but I what I'm hoping to figure out is what I'm not understanding that makes me think $dx^2 + dy^2 = dr^2$ should be correct/ is not making me see why this should be incorrect.

Comment: Saying $dx^2 + dy^2 = dr^2$ is like you've forgotten that you also moved in the $\theta$ direction by some amount. Take a look at the [figure here](http://furqaanyusaf.com/notes/vectors/polar-grad). It "shows" you that you forgot to account for one part of the displacement. That's why there should be an extra term, and it turns out the correct formula is $dx^2 + dy^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d \theta^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Whether Cartesian or Polar, we use Pythagoras thm hypotenuse to find differential arc length and thereafter integrate it.

Just think of differentials temporarily as if they are *finite side lengths* to start with and use Pythagoras:

[image]

Cartesian
$$ PQ^2 = ds^2= dx^2+dy^2 = (1+y^{'2})\; dx^2 $$
Polar
$$ PQ^2= ds^2= dr^2 + (r d\theta)^2 = (r^{'2}+ r^2)\; d\theta^2$$

Do not try Cartesian to Polar conversion at the raw stage. Think of differential lengths *independently*.

Next integrate the differential arc length $ds$ with respect to the independent variable $x$ or $ \theta$.

*Cartesian*

$$ s= \int \sqrt{ (1+y^{'2})}\;dx\;$$

*Polar*

$$ s= \int \sqrt{ r^{'2}+ r^2}\;  d \theta $$

I got rid of my doubts about arc length and individual differential lengths in this trigonometrical way ( sketching Pythagorean differential triangles is in fact stronger than just an intuition ) much earlier once and for all.

EDIT1:

We can extend these to 3d:

*Cartesian*

$$ s= \int \sqrt{ (x^{'2}+y^{'2}+z^{'2})}\;ds\;$$

*Polar*

$$ s= \int \sqrt{r^2+r^{'2}+z^{'2}}\; d \theta $$

Answer (score 0):

$(dx,dy)$ describes a displacement in an arbitrary direction. It can be decomposed in a radial displacement ($dr$) and a trangential one ($r\,d\theta$) and we have the identity

$$dx^2+dy^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2.$$

---

We can check this by direct computation by expanding

$$dx^2+dy^2=(dr\cos\theta-r\sin\theta\,d\theta)^2+(dr\sin\theta-r\cos\theta\,d\theta)^2.$$

In other words,

$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2+r^2\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2}$$

and $$\frac{ds}{d\theta}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2+r^2}.$$